# Making a News Category Classifier using LSTM

Tags: tensorflow, machine-learning, keras, nlp, lstm

I am making a news classification model using LSTM. When I train the model my training accuracy keeps on improving but validation accuracy is not increasing beyond 57%. I have nearly 200k news paragraphs and classifying them into 30 different categories.

My model is as follow:

```
model=Sequential()
model.add(Embedding(30000,64,input_length=X_train.shape[1],mask_zero=True))
model.add(Bidirectional(LSTM(64)))
model.add(Dropout(0.5))
model.add(Dense(64,activation='relu'))
model.add(Dense(30))
model.add(Activation(activation='softmax'))
model.compile(loss="categorical_crossentropy",optimizer='adam',metrics=['accuracy'])
```

Comment: This question is too broad, we don't have access to your database and training setting.

Comment: I appologize for not providing sufficient information.Actually I am new  to stackoverflow.What data should I provide and how ?

Answer (score 0):

First of all, for 30 classes the randomized baseline accuracy is **(100/30) = 3.33%**, so your model is doing good enough.

You didn't provide more details like what's the input length, how long the paragraphs are, are you doing any pre-processing like removing stop words, how you're truncating your paragraphs to all have same length `input_length`.

Another isssue can be class imbalance, probably for some classes you have too few examples. Try removing them or augmenting the dataset to make the classes balanced.

I solved a similar problem, the news category classification but for Bangla, Bangla news category classification is definitely more challenging than doing it for English.

I used a BiLSTM model which achieved 91%+ test accuracy without any serious hyperparameter tuning.

This is the model I used:

```
from keras.models import Sequential
from keras.layers import Embedding, CuDNNLSTM, Bidirectional, Dense

embedding_dim = 8

model = Sequential()
model.add(Embedding(input_dim=vocab_size, 
                           output_dim=embedding_dim, 
                           input_length=maxlen))
model.add(Bidirectional(CuDNNLSTM(128, return_sequences = True)))
model.add(Bidirectional(CuDNNLSTM(128))) 
model.add(Dense(9, activation='softmax'))
model.compile(optimizer='adam',
              loss='categorical_crossentropy',
              metrics=['accuracy'])
model.summary()
```

Full code for Bangla News category classification: https://github.com/zabir-nabil/bangla-news-rnn

Now, you didn't plot your validation accuracy vs training accuracy but I'm assuming your training accuracy is higher. So, your model is overfitted. Maybe reduce the parameters in the Embedding layer.

You can use Google News embedding as a weight initializer for your Embedding layer. https://github.com/mmihaltz/word2vec-GoogleNews-vectors

The best approach would be using a BERT-like language model to get really good accuracy. https://github.com/huggingface/transformers

Comment: I appologize for not providing sufficient information.Actually I am new  to stackoverflow.What data should I provide and how ?

Comment: Which dataset you're using? Also first try the steps I mentioned, if they don't help you can expand your question with more details.

Comment: I have downloaded the dataset from kaggle.Link to dataset https://www.kaggle.com/rmisra/news-category-dataset. I have removed the stopwords.I have used most frequent top 30000 words and truncated the paragraph to length 100 only.